# C++ lambda implementation in runtime

Tags: c++, objective-c, lambda, objective-c-blocks, objective-c++

In Objective-C we know that blocks have 3 implementations in runtime.

1. `NSGlobalBlock` - that is singleton in runtime, and it is created in case we don't use values of stack variables.
2. `NSStackBlock` - that is not singleton, and it is allocated on stack (not on heap), and it is created when we use some stack variables.
3. `NSMallocBlock` - that is allocated on heap, and that is used when we want to store Blocks as ivar or property of some Class, or anywhere in heap f.e. `@property (nonatomic, copy) MyBlockType myBlock;` or when we use `Block_copy()` function. It is really important because NSMallocBlock retains objects from context, and this fact can create some owning cycles, if we do not use blocks correct.

So, my question is: "Where can I find the full explanation C++ lambdas runtime, and how they are processed by Compiler? Or could you explain that? Is there any specific issues with memory management using C++ lambdas? Where lambdas are allocated, on heap or on stack?"

Comment: "and it is created in case we don't change values of stack variables using __block modifier." No. `NSGlobalBlock` is for blocks that are not *closures*, i.e. that don't capture any local variables from an outside scope. "and it is created when we use _block modifiers for some stack variables." No. Again, it is for any blocks that are *closures*, i.e. that use a local variable from an outside scope. It doesn't have to a `__block` variable.

Comment: @newacct you are right, NSGlobalBlock just can use static variables, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas implementation is compiler-specific.

The standard doesn't specify where it is allocated memory-wise, but **as a rule of thumb, they are roughly equivalent to [old-school functors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/356950)** and they and their captured values are copied on the stack, like any normal object.

E.g.

```
std::vector<int> v{10,11,12,13};
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int& i) {i++;});
```

would be just a stateless function.

Or,

```
std::vector<int> v{10,11,12,13};
int C = 10;
int D = 20;
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [C,&D](int& i) {i += C + D;});
```

would be equivalent to a functor constructed on the stack with a copy of `C`, and a reference to `D` as its members (but likely would be optimised away).

The only time you really place a lambda object on the heap is when it's converted to `std::function`, How it's done is dependent on compiler's implementation of `std::function`.

```
void g(const std::function& f);
// ...
auto f = [=](int& i){i += C;}; // still on the stack (compiler-specific type)
g(f); // std::function constructed, possibly on the heap
```